# Adding recessed lighting to ceiling fan switch

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, recessed-lighting

I currently have a single ceiling fan controller by two light switches (at the same location), one for light on fan, one for fan only, or Both switched on for light and fan. I replaced my fan with a light to a fan without a light. It has 14/3 wire.

My question is what is the best way to install 2 led recessed lights?

The attic is narrow but assuming I can get to the ceiling box in the attic. Can I run 14/2 romex from the ceiling fan junction box to recessed lights? Wire white to white, black to red (Assuming fan is off black), ground to ground and do the same at my recessed lights?

And if I didn’t want to tap into the ceiling fan Or can’t reach it can I just run 14/2 from the new recessed lights to my current light switch box on the wall, into a new light switch then pig tale to main power line?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. The easiest way would be to extend the wiring from the ceiling fan box to the new recessed lighting cans and connect them the way you listed.

You could also run additional wire from the switch box to the recessed light location but running new wire down a wall would probably be harder than tapping into the ceiling fan box. From your description, it appears the feed source is into the switch box so you'd be OK, just cap of the the unused wire from the 14/3 (red from your description) to the ceiling box at both locations.

Comment: Do I have to worry about any of the box size calculations that are involved with outlet plug boxes? Where bringing in extra wires to the ceiling fan would require I get a larger cubic area junction box?

Comment: @user903805  What are outlet plug boxes?  I don't think you'll have a problem but look inside the boxes. They should say what the cu in's are. Let us know.

Comment: Like I’ve added a few extra 2 gauge outlets around my house, like behind my wall mounted tv. And the electrics boxes I taped into were only 20 cubic inches so when I added an extra 14/2 wire into it, it exceeded the electrical box volume calculations and I had to install a bigger electrical box (was 1 14/2 in, 1 14/2 out, pig tails/wire nuts, 1 duplex outlet) (when added the extra 1 14/2 wire I exceeded the volume allowed in the box). Sounds like ceiling fans don’t have those same volume max fill requirements. 

I’ll check the volume on the fan box when I open it but it seemed large